# Moodle - Custom New User Notification

Tags: email, moodle, placeholder

I'm having a problem with customizing a Moodle Email.

The Moodle Administrators get an email telling them a new user has created an account, I'm using [this](https://docs.moodle.org/30/en/Email-based_self-registration).

It is working perfectly but I'm trying to customize the email placeholders because it sends the whole userdata which is not needed.

I just wanted to send the name and the email.

This is my code:

```
Olá Administrador, uma nova conta requisitou aprovação com a seguinte informação:
Nome: {$a->firstname}
Email: {$a->email}
Para confirmar a conta vá a este link {$a->link}
Pode também confirmar a conta no Moodle navegando na Administração do Site -> Utilizadores -> Contas -> Ver lista
```

{$a->firstname} works "fine" as it shows the complete name of the new user BUT {$a->email} doesn't work at all, it displays as it is in the code: "Email: {$a->email}".

I've tried emailaddress, email, mail, etc. I can't find a working placeholder for the email.

Where can I find the list of placeholders that I can use? I really don't want to use {$a->userdata} because it shows really too much, since ID's and meaningless stuff for the Administrator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to modify the core code to do that.

Have a look at `function send_confirmation_email()` in `/lib/moodlelib.php`

Then look for stringid `emailconfirmation` in that function.

The get_string() is passing $data, this is used for the placeholders.

Above that is

```
$data = new stdClass();
$data->firstname = fullname($user);
$data->sitename  = format_string($site->fullname);
$data->admin     = generate_email_signoff();
```

So only firstname, sitename and admin are available.

You will need to add the email to $data eg:

```
$data->email = $user->email;
```

Then you can use {$a->email} as a placeholder.

Comment: I might be doing something wrong or that doesn't work.
I even tried using their method: `$data->email= email($user);` and it still didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Is the place holder {$a->email} still in the message?

Comment: yes it is. It is displaying as Email: {$a->email} like it wasn't a placeholder...

Comment: do you happen to know any other solution?

Comment: ah, then its the wrong stringid. See if you can find the original text and then tell me what the stringid is. It will be something like $string['stringid'] = 'your message'; - when you find the stringid, then search all the code for the id to see where its being used. Then see what data is being passed to it.

Comment: should I search for that stringid inside the function? EDIT: Oh wait, are you talking about the stringid that appears when I'm customizing the language? If you do, it's this 'auth_emailadminconfirmation'

Comment: Yeah, so search for 'auth_emailadminconfirmation' in the code. It will be something like get_string('auth_emailadminconfirmation', 'auth_email', $data); The $data parameter will need to have an email property.

Comment: Should I still search inside moodlelib.php? If yes, I can't find anything. I searched for: auth_email, auth_emailadmin and auth_emailadminconfirmation. None of them found a result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102624/discussion-between-russell-england-and-white8tiger).